# Changing URL when redirecting to another page

Tags: html, css, redirect

I am currently trying to redirect a link in my website to **secure.mywebsite.com.**

The problem is that every time I click the link, the address bar displays **www.mywebsite.com** instead of **secure.mywebsite.com**. The page is re-directed fine and it displays well without any problem. The only problem is that the address bar shows the wrong url. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
<li class="menuItem"><a href="http://secure.mywebsite.com">Login</a></li>
```

Comment: @AzeezKallayi Yes in all browsers

Comment: How u r redirecting ? From your control panel , or just put redirection code in your index file?

Comment: is this a new domain you created? you might need to clear your cache and try again, on my side it directs just fine

Comment: @AzeezKallayi Just redirection from my index file.

Comment: @MariusBrits Thats strange. It's not working for me. I am redirecting mywebsite.com to a vaadin application hosted on openshift with the url secure.mywebsite.com.